# yarn is crashing due to some node gyp and node-sass related issues

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, node-gyp, node-sass

I tried many different answers from github issues and stackoverflow, but its not resolved.

Could this be an OS related issue? I currently tried on windows and ubuntu. ps: the project works on MacOS without any errors
node - 16.13.0
node sass in project v6.0.0,
os - ubuntu 20 lts
python, build essentials installed.

error log :

```
   make: *** [deasync.target.mk:113: Release/obj.target/deasync/src/deasync.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/sandrin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.13.0-40-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/sandrin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node" "/home/sandrin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/sandrin/.cache/yarn/v6/.tmp/c7cdac7c2a9ce67dc3216b3d4e04aab2.9416114cb72b213593bf054fa28cd205f526e5f3.prepare/node_modules/deasync
gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
make: Leaving directory '/home/sandrin/.cache/yarn/v6/.tmp/c7cdac7c2a9ce67dc3216b3d4e04aab2.9416114cb72b213593bf054fa28cd205f526e5f3.prepare/node_modules/deasync/build'



[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/1] ⠂ node-sass
```

the process is getting stuck in node-sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch from [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) to [`sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass) (aka Dart Sass).

`node-sass` (which uses a native module that you're evidently having trouble compiling) is deprecated; quote from the npm page for `node-sass`:

> Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

Comment: but why is the project running perfectly on macOS? with same node and python versions? Because this project has other old project dependancies which is using node-sass.

Comment: Likely because the Windows and Ubuntu boxes are missing some build dependencies, or have an incompatible version of the C compiler (e.g. one with stricter warnings than what may have passed on macOS).

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback. I will try installing it on debian 10( which is currently the project is hosted) and will update here

Comment: we finally updated every node-sass dependancy project to sass, and the problem got fixed. basically the issue was with python versions. npm searches python and pick python3 instead of python2 for old node sass versions. Even on mac, the issue was persisting on macOS 12.3 + ( where mac removed python2 from /usr/bin)